# Get value of an HTML attribute using class name without id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this below code. I just want the value of `data-pkid` attribute in the form of list with JavaScript or JQuery using class name only and without using id.
I want to run that particular JS or JQuery on developer console of this [Game site](https://pkmn.pw/VoraArsh.N/trade)

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row hoverclr-electric" id="pokeR7gc32" data-pktype="electric" data-pkid="R7gc32"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-dark" id="pokemwvxW2" data-pktype="dark" data-pkid="mwvxW2"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-electric" id="pokezZLTRJ" data-pktype="electric" data-pkid="zZLTRJ"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-fairy" id="pokej5qWHs" data-pktype="fairy" data-pkid="j5qWHs"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-psychic" id="pokezmhrwv" data-pktype="psychic" data-pkid="zmhrwv"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-psychic" id="pokemVVB5Q" data-pktype="psychic" data-pkid="mVVB5Q"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-psychic" id="pokez26VC5" data-pktype="psychic" data-pkid="z26VC5"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-psychic" id="poker3VGC" data-pktype="psychic" data-pkid="r3VGC"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-psychic" id="pokeTL75r2" data-pktype="psychic" data-pkid="TL75r2"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-psychic" id="pokeBVJ9kC" data-pktype="psychic" data-pkid="BVJ9kC"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-rock" id="pokeR5FGJC" data-pktype="rock" data-pkid="R5FGJC"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-psychic" id="pokeBVxyy2" data-pktype="psychic" data-pkid="BVxyy2"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-water" id="pokeTnZkCP" data-pktype="water" data-pkid="TnZkCP"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-water" id="pokehybjcD" data-pktype="water" data-pkid="hybjcD"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-water" id="pokemVy88w" data-pktype="water" data-pkid="mVy88w"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-grass" id="pokeTLr6ph" data-pktype="grass" data-pkid="TLr6ph"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-water" id="pokeL2QFTB" data-pktype="water" data-pkid="L2QFTB"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-grass" id="pokerHMHR" data-pktype="grass" data-pkid="rHMHR"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-poison" id="pokeTgdd1w" data-pktype="poison" data-pkid="Tgdd1w"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-poison" id="pokeLLNZx3" data-pktype="poison" data-pkid="LLNZx3"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-poison" id="poke5wTPv5" data-pktype="poison" data-pkid="5wTPv5"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-water" id="pokeR5Qhnk" data-pktype="water" data-pkid="R5Qhnk"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-psychic" id="pokebZw5K5" data-pktype="psychic" data-pkid="bZw5K5"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-psychic" id="pokeLLFq81" data-pktype="psychic" data-pkid="LLFq81"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-psychic" id="pokehG7WbY" data-pktype="psychic" data-pkid="hG7WbY"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-psychic" id="pokeBVJCR3" data-pktype="psychic" data-pkid="BVJCR3"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-psychic" id="poke5p2yLt" data-pktype="psychic" data-pkid="5p2yLt"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-rock" id="pokemVr59D" data-pktype="rock" data-pkid="mVr59D"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-water" id="pokef4XXQh" data-pktype="water" data-pkid="f4XXQh"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-water" id="pokebZQ5Wf" data-pktype="water" data-pkid="bZQ5Wf"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-psychic" id="pokeTLnrss" data-pktype="psychic" data-pkid="TLnrss"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-ground" id="pokemNMVQ5" data-pktype="ground" data-pkid="mNMVQ5"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-steel" id="pokeLLZYNT" data-pktype="steel" data-pkid="LLZYNT"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-fire" id="poke5VMNV3" data-pktype="fire" data-pkid="5VMNV3"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-fire" id="pokesrP8xW" data-pktype="fire" data-pkid="srP8xW"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-steel" id="pokeyy9vVV" data-pktype="steel" data-pkid="yy9vVV"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-psychic" id="poke592SQ4" data-pktype="psychic" data-pkid="592SQ4"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-steel" id="pokeBqz232" data-pktype="steel" data-pkid="Bqz232"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-steel" id="pokebmHgZF" data-pktype="steel" data-pkid="bmHgZF"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-psychic" id="poker3VPv" data-pktype="psychic" data-pkid="r3VPv"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-fire" id="pokebxLzKp" data-pktype="fire" data-pkid="bxLzKp"></div>
    <div class="row hoverclr-fire" id="pokeBV3vL1" data-pktype="fire" data-pkid="BV3vL1"></div>
</div>
```

How can I get output as below form

- [pokecard]R7gc32[/pokecard]
- [pokecard]mwvxW2[/pokecard]
- [pokecard]zZLTRJ[/pokecard]
- [pokecard]j5qWHs[/pokecard]

and so on.......
I tried following code

```js
var test = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
test.getAttribute("data-pkid");
```

Even I looked answers from may website but didn't found useful.

Comment: `$('.row').each(function() { console.log($(this).data('pkid')) })`

Comment: @zer00ne It really worked bro thank you very much.

Comment: now it can be used as
`$('.row').each(function() { 
    console.log("[pokecard]" + $(this).data('pkid') + "[/pokecard]")
})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some other methods to get the same result
1

```
document.querySelectorAll('.container>div').forEach(n=> )
 console.log(`[pokecard]${n.getAttribute('data-pkid')}[/pokecard]\n`)
)
```

2

```
 document.querySelectorAll('.row').forEach(n=> 
 console.log(`[pokecard]${n.getAttribute('data-pkid')}[/pokecard]\n`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an issue because there are 42 objects with class name  'row'.
'test' references an HTML collection of 42 elements. Since it is an HTML object we can't itrate it with forEach method but we can do it with normal loops for example for loop

```
for(i=0;i<test.length;i++){
   console.log(`[pokecard]${test[i].getAttribute('data-pkid')}[/pokecard]`)
}
```

Comment: there is nothing called `test` here.

Comment: var test = document.getElementsByClassName("row");

I was referencing his test variable